# Does this use of angular.extend serve any purpose?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've inherited a codebase which contains the following code snippet (simplified from its source to reduce the number of parameters and anonymise the code, whilst maintaining the general behaviour):

```
/**
 * @param {float} a
 * @param {string} b
 * @param {string} c
 * @param {boolean} d
 & @return (object)
    */
srv.pack = function(a , b , c , d)
{
    return angular.extend({} , {
        a: a ,
        e: d ? b : c , 
        f: d ? c : b
    });
};
```

Based on my reading of the documentation for [`angular.extend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend#!) it seems like this use of `angular.extend` serves no purpose and the code could be simplified by its removal. Is this the case, or is there a nuance here that I'm unaware of due to my inexperience with AngularJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ! since you are creating the object you want to copy right there, just before copying it, you could just return the object directly.

We usually use `angular.extend`, `Object.assign` or `let clone = {...original}` to avoid mutating objects that we are later going to use in rendering.

Now, in most cases, angular won't detect a change in an object in its scope, if you are mutating/altering its properties. But if you completely rewrite that object with a clone and then change the properties, rendering will be triggered.

But in your case, there is no need to be doing any such thing, your function is actually creating a new object each time it is being called, so you can safely remove angular.extend.

Comment: @Archer angular.extend is copying the object from param 2 to param 1. he is creating an object in param 2, which is being copied to param 1

Comment: I suspected that was the case (based on having grokked the code for `angular.extend` as well) but wanted some confirmation that it wasn't either (a) a convention, or (b) something I'd missed! Thanks :-)